# How to change the screen size of vmlite android?

Tags: android, vmlite

I installed [vmlite's android image](http://www.vmlite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=69&Itemid=178) which is great but there is one thing I don't find solution: How to change the screen size?

It has a fix ratio of the width/height of the screen, but I need to change it to simulate some android phones.

I searched a lot but not find a solution, please help.

---

**UPDATE**

The grub menu is as following:

1. cmdline (hd0,2)/cmdline
2. kernel --use-cmd-line (hd0,2)/kernel
3. initrd (hd0,2)/ramdisk

I haved add a custom size using this command:

```
VBoxManage.exe setextradata "android-vmlite" "CustomVideoMode1" "480x800x32"
```

Then add `vga-ask` to all of the 3 menu options, but none works.

When press `b` on them, it doesn't ask to choose model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've done some research and finally was able to edit the virtual box image. Here's how:

If you go to vmlite image's grub entries on boot , the kernel entry (one with "kernel" keyword) has an argument `--use-cmd-line` , this `cmdline` is defined in the first entry `cmdline (hd0,2)/cmdline`, which is a file called `cmdline` placed inside boot hard disk's third partition.

This file has the kernel options:

```
init=/init qemu=1 console=ttyS0 console=tty0 vga=788 verbose androidboot.hardware=vbox_x86 androidboot.console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1
```

Now you must edit this file called cmdline to change `vga=788` option to `vga=ask`.

**Editing: (on a Linux machine)**

You need to install `vdfuse`.

> `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-fuse`

create two empty folders somewhere.

> `sudo mkdir /mnt/image`
>
> `sudo mkdir /mnt/partition`

Then mount the virtual box image (vdi, vmdk or vhd etc) to a folder. (Lets say virtualbox disk image file is `/tmp/vmlite.vmdk` and we'll mount it to `/mnt/image` folder)

> `vdfuse -w  -f  /tmp/vmlite.vmdk   /mnt/image`

Some files will be created in mount folder named *EntireDisk*, *Partition1* , *Partition2*, *Partition3* and so on.

since we are interested in third partition, we will mount the corresponding file to `/mnt/partition`:

> `sudo mount -o loop /mnt/image/Partition3  /mnt/partition`

See the contents:

> `sudo ls -l /mnt/partition`

There'd be cmdline, ramdisk and kernel.

Now we edit the cmdline file (we'll use gedit text editor, you can use one you like):

> `sudo gedit /mnt/partiton/cmdline`

make the edits, change `vga=788` to `vga=ask`, save and close. Verify new file contents:

> `sudo cat /mnt/partition/cmdline`

Unmount files and images:

> `sudo umount /mnt/partition`
>
> `sudo umount /mnt/image`

and if we don't need those two folders:

> `sudo rm /mnt/image`
>
> `sudo rm /mnt/partition`

Done,  boot image from virtual box. It'll say press ENTER to view available video modes, On Enter a list is shown, type the digit of choice, or type "scan" to search for more display modes.

**NOTE:** Not all modes worked ,use VESA modes with color depth 24 or 32 and supported aspect ratios.

Comment: Thanks again, it works great! Now I can set the screen to 480x800x32 and 800x1280x32 :) The only strange thing is the color of my application is changed, seems 8bit or 16bit, not as beautiful as before.

Comment: The problem is fixed when I change my custom color depth to 16: `800x1280x16` :)

Comment: I can't stop myself to thank you again :) You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: 16 bit works ? not on my machine though. I'm glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this thread:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=19785371

You can change this file, cmdline, inside (hd0,2)

init=/init qemu=1 console=ttyS0 console=tty0 vga=788 verbose androidboot.hardware=vbox_x86 androidboot.console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1

==>

init=/init qemu=1 console=ttyS0 console=tty0 vga=ask verbose androidboot.hardware=vbox_x86 androidboot.console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1

Thank wingman for his detailed instructions.

Another option is to attach the vmdk file to a running linux vm (if you have one), the disk would auto mount to make life simpler.

Comment: did you modify cmdline file? I just tested, it will display a list of resolutions, press Space bar

Comment: Are you using vmlite android image: http://www.vmlite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=69&Itemid=178 ?

Comment: yes, I am the author of that vm, will release jelly bean vm next month, most likely

Comment: Nice to see you and thanks for your great work, it saved me ton of time. Hope it support defining custom screen size easily in the next release :)