# Run Android x86 with 256 colors

Tags: android, operating-system, x86, android-x86, color-depth

I'm trying to run Android x86 in 256 colors mode. Is there any setting like in Windows OS that I can change and make the all Android OS system run in 8bit colors mode? Or should I suppose to recompile the Android x86 with some kernel modifications?

Comment: enable `vga=ask` in boot options, then select required mode. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12509879/1531054

Comment: It's generally an embedded Linux (modified though; e.g. no */etc/passwd*). Research Linux methods of setting these properties.