# How to tuning Androidx86 as fast as Genymotion?

Tags: android

I am using Genymotion for android development.
And it is very fast and responsible.

However,Genymotion doesn't allow i change the DPI and custom resolution to emulate the real device.

So i would turn to AndroidX86 and follow the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202342/switch-android-x86-screen-resolution) to change the resolution.
Actually AndroidX86 is not fast as Genymotion.
And i believe Genymotion OS image is also using Androidx86, so anybody know anythings that Genymotion made,so it's faster than origin?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Android x86 and its very fast. You need to make sure that you install HAXM driver.

You also need to make sure Virtualization is enabled for your BIOS.

Comment: Check out this article:http://www.developer.com/ws/android/development-tools/haxm-speeds-up-the-android-emulator.html

Comment: Android x86 is a port of Android running on x86 hardware such as real PC or virtualbox/vmware, not Intel image in AVD Manager

Comment: How can i turn on HAXM driver support on Androidx86? I alreadly install the HAXM driver via Android SDK manager.