# Android in VirtualBox - Win 7 with 32bit color depth

Tags: android, virtualbox, resolution, android-x86, color-depth

I have added custom resolutions on Android 4.3 virtual machine in VirtualBox (installed on Windows 7 32-bit), but I manage only to work with them if they use 16bit color depth. If I set 24bit, virtual machine doesn't boot, if I set 32bit, it shows two small screens that cover upper portion of screen.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is some explanation on this thread that sounds promising.  Give it a try;

[Switch android x86 screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202342/switch-android-x86-screen-resolution)

Comment: I have started from that question and came so far to this problem.

But thanks for trying.