# Android x86 resolution

Tags: android, resolution

Hi How do I set my screen resolution to 1280x700 if it accepts 320x480x16?

Whats the meaning of x16 on the last part?

Can I have

```
1280x700x16
```

as a galaxy nexus resolution?

in my Virtualbox with this command.

```
VBoxManage setextradata "VM_NAME_HERE" "CustomVideoMode1" "320x480x16"
```

Comment: The 16 is the [color depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth), and indicates 16 bits per pixel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6202342/752320

Answer (score -1):

16 is the bit depth for more information see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth