# Android-x86 on VirtualBox restarts whenever an app is closed

Tags: virtualbox, android-x86

I am using Android-x86 6.0 on VirtualBox. Since I have changed the screen resolution using the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8273560/6110243 Android restarts whenever an open app is exited through the home or back button. This happens for every application, system apps and user apps. I can still use the back button to navigate within an application, but once the back button closes the app it instantly shows the "android" logo and boots back up.

I suspect it might be because my battery level always shows "0%" (and charging) and it somehow triggers a shutdown when an app is closed? But that wouldn't explain why it only started happening after I changed the resolution from the standard resolustion to 600x800x32. I have tried to set the Battery level to something higher, but couldn't find any Information on how to do so.

Comment: The same was happening to me when changing the LCI density in the "cm-x86-13.0-r1" Android settings. I had to change it back to the default.

Comment: i got the same exact problem even though the battery level is 98. so i believe we can rule out battery affecting it. ps. im testing on android 6 atm.