# How to set a custom resolution on Android-x86 VM running in VMware Fusion

Tags: android-x86, vmware-fusion

I created an Android-x86 8.1-r1 VM using Vmware Fusion 11.0.3 for Mac, and I need to change its screen resolution to 1080x1920.

I tried to change the resolution following the instructions contained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8273560/2970468).

I edited the `/mnt/grub/menu.lst` accordingly, but I don't know if there is in VMWare a command equivalent to this Virtual Box command:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "VM_NAME_HERE" "CustomVideoMode1" "1080x1920x32"
```

So, without telling VMware about that custom resolution like it's done in Virtual Box (I don't know if it's really needed), whenever I turn the VM on, I can see the initial terminal messages, but then the screen goes black and nothing happens.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Try adding 'nomodeset' and 'vga=ask' to GRUB boot arguments, as mentioned in responses to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202342/switch-android-x86-screen-resolution

Here is an explanation of how to do it: https://helpahoy.tech.blog/2018/08/22/how-to-change-the-screen-resolution-dpi-on-android-x86/