# Virtualbox even with guest addition only allows me odd resolutions. will it be flagged as VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, resolution, screen-resolution

so i need to trick a browser extension so it will not know that I am using a virtual machine, in my opinion i did pretty well with all the other stuff, spoof MAC adress, go into the registry editor and change some names for camera, have realistic number of cores,ram, rom etc. etc.

now i installed guest additions so im not stuck with an unrealistic small res. and when i full screen my vm, the max res i can get is 2560x1335 while my monitor is 2560x1440. i turned it down to 1920x1440 and all the other options are also odd.

i cant get a normal res, will this be flagged as a virtual machine now?

Comment: solution foundhttps://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1298/how-to-run-a-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox-with-a-custom-resolution-3840x2160

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202342/switch-android-x86-screen-resolution